# GAE NDB AttributeError model instance has no attribute

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a Google App Engine NDB model called 'Bin'. **I have modified the properties for 'Bin' and deleted all data entries that correspond to the older model.** My goal is to query for all bins and access the attribute 'label' inside a GAE Endpoints function. However, when querying and iterating through the returned list I get `AttributeError: 'Bin' object has no attribute 'label'`, which is clearly false. Log output shows that the returned list does in fact contain two Bin objects that have an attribute called 'label'.

What is interesting is that when I change code around the query, the code will work properly for the next run. Then it fails again.

I have cleared the memcache, restarted the app engine launcher and deleted all entries (then adding new ones) in an attempt to remove any caching.

#### NDB Model

```
class Bin(ndb.Model):
    id=ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    label=ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    items=ndb.JsonProperty()
```

#### The Query

```
import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote
from includes.models import Bin
...
@endpoints.api(name='iwora', version='v1')
class Api(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, BinCollection,
    path='bin', http_method='GET',
    name='bin.all')
    def bin_all(self, request):
        self.user_required()

        namespace = namespace_manager.get_namespace()
        try:
            namespace_manager.set_namespace(self.user.active_org)
            bins = Bin.query().fetch()
            logging.info('BINS: %s' % bins)
            binsresponse = []
            for bin in bins:
                logging.info('BIN: %s' % bin)
                obj = {
                    'label': bin.label # error happens here
                }
                binsresponse.append(obj)
        finally:
            namespace_manager.set_namespace(namespace)

        return BinCollection(bins=binsresponse)
...
```

When the query is ran and I attempt to iterate through the returned bins I get the following output:

> BINS: [Bin(key=Key('Bin', 'default_bin', 'Bin', 5275456790069248),
>   id=2L, items=None, label='1-1-2'), Bin(key=Key('Bin', 'default_bin',
>   'Bin', 5838406743490560), id=1L, items=None, label='1-1-1')]
>       BIN: Bin(key=Key('Bin', 'default_bin', 'Bin', 5275456790069248), id=2L, items=None, label='1-1-2')
>       Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: AttributeError ('Bin' object has no attribute 'label')
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py",
>   line 181, in protorpc_service_app
>       response = method(instance, request)
>       File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-
>   default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py",
>   line 1332, in invoke_remote
>       return remote_method(service_instance, request)
>       File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py",
>   line 412, in invoke_remote_method
>       response = method(service_instance, request)
>       File "/Users/rlfrahm/Apps/iwora/api.py", line 524, in bin_all
>       'label': bin.label
>       AttributeError: 'Bin' object has no attribute 'label'

I think (as in I believe, but have not confirmed) that this only happens once I have implemented a model, added entries into the db, and then modified the model either by changing a property name or adding a new property. Even after deleting the entries I still experience this issue. I realize that this issue is not repeatable in its current state because I do not exactly know how to reproduce the error. It seems to "just happen." I have many other functions that use this same process and work just fine. Even the interactive console in the SDK Console returns correctly.

Therefore, I am really wondering if anyone has seen this type of behavior or sees something obviously wrong with my process?

Comment: You're clearly showing us only part of your code (you set but never use `binsresponse` and `obj`, for example) and I suspect the damage happens in the parts you're omitting, making it impossible for us to help you debug.  Please post a concise *but complete* failing example, maybe using `testbed` to make it really stand-alone...

Comment: In addition looking at the first line logged you can see each of the Bin instances retrieved do in fact have a label attribute.  The fact that iterating over the list of Bins and somehow you are causing ProtoRPC calls and that looks strange.  You are omitting a lot of information.

Comment: @AlexMartelli - I have updated the description. The query and iteration happen within a GAE Endpoints function. There are other functions alongside this function that do similar queries on different models and they work just fine.

Comment: @TimHoffman - The query resides inside a GAE Endpoints function. I have updated the op with more information. Let me know what else you want to know.

Comment: @frahminator, I've edited the tags to include google-cloud-endpoints which you had omitted -- now I can try to reproduce your actual problem.

Comment: ...and as you expected I can't reproduce it because, as the Q now says, it's likely tied to changing a model while entries are in the DB (even if those entries are then deleted).  What I've done when needing to change a schema: first dump all existing entries, delete them all from the DB, THEN change the schema, reload all needed entries through a dedicated handler that does the renaming & whatever. A pain, but I know of no other safe way.

Comment: @AlexMartelli - Thank you for your help and I appreciate your advice on migrating schemas. This issue is VERY hit and miss which is why I haven't figured out the cause and have turned to the community for help. I will continue to update the op while I learn more.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my best attempt at trying to reproduce your error -- it includes all the sparse fragments of code you've deigned to share with us, and miserably fails to show any error at all.

```
import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Bin(ndb.Model):
    id=ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    label=ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    items=ndb.JsonProperty()

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        bins = Bin.query().fetch()
        if not bins:
            Bin(id=1L, items=None, label='1-1-1').put()
            Bin(id=2L, items=None, label='1-1-2').put()
            bins = Bin.query().fetch()
        logging.info('BINS: %s' % bins)
        binsresponse = []
        for bin in bins:
            logging.info('BIN: %s' % bin)
            obj = {
                'label': bin.label # error happens here
            }
            binsresponse.append(obj)

        self.response.write('Hello world! ')
        self.response.write(binsresponse)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Running this locally in the SDK shows, as expected:

```
Hello world! [{'label': u'1-1-2'}, {'label': u'1-1-1'}]
```

and the relevant snippet from the log is:

```
INFO     2014-12-21 03:15:56,721 main.py:19] BINS: [Bin(key=Key('Bin', 5066549580791808), id=2, items=None, label=u'1-1-2'), Bin(key=Key('Bin', 5629499534213120), id=1, items=None, label=u'1-1-1')]
INFO     2014-12-21 03:15:56,721 main.py:22] BIN: Bin(key=Key('Bin', 5066549580791808), id=2, items=None, label=u'1-1-2')
INFO     2014-12-21 03:15:56,722 main.py:22] BIN: Bin(key=Key('Bin', 5629499534213120), id=1, items=None, label=u'1-1-1')
```

IOW, no problem whatsoever.

**Please** add to this tiny code (which does include every single last bit you deigned to post!-) what's missing to make it reproduce your error, and edit your question to include the minimum failing example -- or else, give up all hope that anybody will ever be able to help you debug your mistakes!-)